# How extract a column from a 2D array in Perl

Tags: perl, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a specific column of a 2d-array to a function in perl. I only know how to pass a 1darray or a 2d-array.

```
insertDeviceOIDstats(\$dbh, \@deviceMIB);

sub insertDeviceOIDstats{
  # Get passed arguments
  my ($dbh, $MIB) = @_;
  # Get the array from the reference
  my @objectsID = @{$MIB};
...

}
```

Suppose I have a "2d" array `deviceMIB`:

```
+----------------------+-------+
| ubntWlStatRssi       | 29    |
| ubntWlStatSignal     | -67   |
| ubntWlStatCcq        | 91    |
| ubntWlStatNoiseFloor | -96   |
+----------------------+-------+
```

I want the array `@objectsID` or `$MIB` to contain only the following column:

```
+-------+
| 29    |
| -67   |
| 91    |
| -96   |
+-------+
```

How many ways are there for passing only one column to the function and which one is more efficient?

Should I somehow pre-slice the array or is there a way to that while passing the argument with a lamda function or something familiar?

Comment: So that's `@deviceMIB` in your picture, and `$deviceMIB[0]` is `( 'ubntWlStatRssi', 29)`. Right? What do you want `$MIB` to be?

Comment: @Borodin I edited the question a bit to be more specific.

Comment: I don't understand your data structure. What's actually in `@deviceMIB` and what do you want to get out of it (in Perl syntax)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many ways are there for passing only one column to the function and which one is more efficient?

I don't believe you really want to know *how many ways* there are. Suppose I told you there were 42 ways, what would you do with that information?

It's most efficient to just pass the whole array, and use `$MIB->[$i][1]` etc. to get at the second column

---

First of all, `$dbh` is already a reference—in fact it's an object—so there's no need to pass a reference to it

Secondly, I'm guessing that you want the second column of your data, which will need a `map`, either when you call the subroutine or inside it

This code dumps the original `@deviceMIB` and then uses `map` to create an array containing the second column, passing that to the subroutine. It then dumps `$MIB` inside the subroutine

There's no reason to copy `@$MIB` to `@objectsID` so I've left that out—you can simply access the array elements through the reference. In fact there's probably no need to extract the second column at all, as all the information is in the main array, and it's also wasteful as it *copies* all the data in that column

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dump;

my $dbh;

my @deviceMIB = map [ split ], <DATA>;

dd \@deviceMIB;

insertDeviceOIDstats( $dbh, [ map $_->[1], @deviceMIB ] );

sub insertDeviceOIDstats {

    # Get passed arguments
    my ( $dbh, $MIB ) = @_;

    dd $MIB;
}

__DATA__
ubntWlStatRssi        29
ubntWlStatSignal     -67
ubntWlStatCcq         91
ubntWlStatNoiseFloor -96
```

#### output

```
[
  ["ubntWlStatRssi", 29],
  ["ubntWlStatSignal", -67],
  ["ubntWlStatCcq", 91],
  ["ubntWlStatNoiseFloor", -96],
]
[29, -67, 91, -96]
```

Comment: But it seems to me that author has to double check that he always has the same rows with the same names in the same order, if he doesn't want to end up with lots of digits without meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The most readable way is probably to create a new array that just contains the data that you want.

```
my @ids = map { $_->[1] } @deviceMIB;
insertDeviceOIDstats(\$dbh, \@ids);
```

But, as with anything in Perl, it's possible to skip the intermediate `@ids` array:

```
insertDeviceOIDstats(\$dbh, [ map { $_->[1] @deviceMIB } ]);
```

This second approach used `map` to get a list of the IDs you want and the the anonymous array constructor (`[ ... ]`) to turn that into an array and give you a reference to that array.